# Safari is not able to download any files

Tags: safari, permission, data-transfer

Whenever I want to download a file in Safari I get the following message:

> Safari could not download the file XYZ because the disk “Harddisk” doesn’t have enough free space.

I do have enough space on my hard drive and I can typically download the corresponding file via `wget` in a Terminal but it starts to annoy me quite bit.

I tried the following things:

1. `chown` the entire user folder which yielded some errors for various folders:

   ```
   sudo bash
   chown -R thisisme:staff .
   ```
2. Download a linked file to the "Desktop" instead.

None of the things worked out. As a comparison I used Chrome, which worked so it must be something specific to Safari.

[image]
[image]

These are some of the folders (including **Safari** related folders) that weren't `chown`ed:

```
...
chown: ./Library/Sharing: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Sharing: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Mail: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Mail: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Accounts: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Accounts: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Safari: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Safari: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Suggestions: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Suggestions: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes: Operation not permitted
chown: ./Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes: Operation not permitted
...
```